# MySQL Table JOIN Advice

Tags: php, mysql

I wondering what the best advise would be to approach a couple of points. I have a working database where I am able to register new users, create what I call documents and also categories. The tables are set out as the following:

```
Users Tables
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `username` text NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
      `psalt` text NOT NULL


Documents Table
`doc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doc_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `doc_content` text NOT NULL,
  `doc_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `doc_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Categories Table
`cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_title` varchar(32) NOT NULL
```

So when I login as my 1 user currently which is Admin - which two tables join and do I need another table to join them? I am little unclear on how these become related as I tried using the tool to relate them in phpMyadmin (Not the best tool but it what I have to work with). the reason behind this is because if I am logged in as 'Admin' or another user and create a doc I want it to say it was published by that user.

Also, in regards to the documents, they will belong to a category. But I am not sure where the association is. The end result ultimately is that there with will be a number of users who can see different categories and depending on the category are the docs they see.

So, going by your advice I have managed to filter through some data and make it show with SQL.

```
SELECT user_login.id,user_login.username, doc_list.doc_title FROM user_login, doc_list WHERE user_login.id=user_id
```

I have added a new column in the doc_list table called 'user_id' and this is my relation as to who published it. Now, I manually entered the user_id into the fields to make sure I got some results back, but how I am from my php (see below) going to push the user id into the table so its automated?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$hostname='localhost';
$username='######';
$password='######';

try {

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=######",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line

$sql = "INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content, doc_created) VALUES ('".$_POST["doc_title"]."','".$_POST["doc_content"]."', NOW() )";


if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
    header ('Location: ../docList.php');
}
else{
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

Comment: There are no relations among those tables in your example.

Comment: Seems to me you may need a users_Document table and a document_categories Table.  Users_Document shows all the users who can possibly see or edit the document.  Document Categories shows all the categories that the document falls into (assuming it can be more than one)  Presently the tables don't appear to relate at all.

Comment: That is what I am asking for, some advice really. I am not looking for an answer but more of an overview or a starting place.

Comment: @xQbert that sounds pretty much spot on - which of the above columns would need to be related and are you suggesting I create more tables, and if so what rows would be required. I just want to ensure my approach is right?

Comment: The primary keys between the tables would be in the "Associative" tables  So user_Documents would have Users.ID, and Documents.Doc_ID and some indicator to show if the user has C,R,U,D (Create, read Update,Delete) or all privileges (if needed at all).  Doc_Categories would have documents.Doc_Id and categories.cat_Id if you need additional information about the category to document relation, it would go on that table as well. Again assuming that the "ID" fields are your primary keys.  Not null, and no duplicates.  Also assuming docs can have many users and users many docs, and doc many users.

Comment: I have updated my question above, I hope I am getting the idea now.

Comment: the answer depends on if you want the relationship between user and documents to be one-to-many or many-to-many, and similar question for the categories.

Comment: So, the model will be a USER is a part of a GROUP. DOCS are related to the CATEGORY they are in. The GROUPS are related to the CATEGORY so in theory many users can have access to many categories or some may have access to only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the **user-id** which belongs to **Users Table** in **Documents Table** to provide "it was published by that user" and then join Users Tables with Documents Table.